# Missing links in a spdep (R) Queen Contiguity Neighborhood

Tags: r, plot, nearest-neighbor, neighbours, spdep

I'm puzzled by the following result in plotting the Queen Contiguity Neighbors using the `spdep` library in R.

```
library(spdep)
```

Using a World shape file wrld_simp to get the centroid points (spatial coordinates)

```
data(wrld_simpl)
plot(wrld_simpl)
coord.w <- coordinates(wrld_simpl)
ID <- wrld_simpl$IDb
```

To get the Queen contiguity neighbors, I do

```
queen_nb <- poly2nb(wrld_simpl, row.names=ID, queen=TRUE)
```

and then I plot the shape file

```
plot(wrld_simpl, border="grey60",xlab="",ylab="",xlim=NULL, axes=TRUE)
title(main="Queen contiguity neighbors")
```

and the Queen Contiguity Neighbors:

```
plot(queen_nb, coord.w, add=TRUE, col="red", pch=19, cex=0.6)
```

You you plot it (or if you just run `summary(queen_nb)`), you can see that many neighbors are not connected (e.g Chile is an isolate).

Do you have any hints?